# Ruby 3.1.2 - None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am a beginner with ruby on rails

Using Window 10

Ruby version 3.1.2p20

Rails version 7.0.3

When I run `rails server`, I see:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.3 application starting in development       
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:159:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:156:in `create_default_data_source'
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
...
D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_sources/zoneinfo_data_source.rb:232:in `initialize': None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories. (TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound)
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:157:in `new'
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:157:in `create_default_data_source'
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
...
```

I'm following doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and I can't create a model because of this error.

Comment: Did you try to run the command from the error message? It suggests „ Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install“

Comment: but Gemfile has '''gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]'''

Comment: Trust, but verify. If you run `bundle list` does it show `tzinfo-data` is present or not?

Comment: has ```tzinfo (2.0.4)``` only

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same problem with the same configuration and the solution is very simple open your Gemfile file and change line 39-40 like this:

```
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data"
```

deleting all the information about the platform. As described in this github discussion:
[TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound for new Rails application (Ruby 3.1.0 on Windows)](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/128)
it should be an "*issue with x64_mingw not matching for Ruby 3.1.0 x64 Windows builds*".

Hope it helps,
Stefano.

Comment: Thank you I just removed the last part from the tzinfo-data and it worked